# How to use Keras.backend in TensorflowJS?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

```
from keras import backend as K
layer_name ='Mask'
NewInput = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
visualization = K.function([model.input], [NewInput])
```

I want to write above code in Tensorflow.JS

I am unable to find the right lines in TensorflowJS for this code snippet.

Can anyone help ?!

Comment: As far as I know keras backend is not supported in Tensorflow.js

Comment: There must be some way for us to use it.

Comment: Isn't there an alternative for this?